# Maximum number of colors that can be used for the vertices of a eight-dimensional hypercube

Tags: combinatorics, coding-theory

What is the maximum number of the colors what can be used to color the vertices of a eight-dimensional hypercube, such that for every vertex of the cube, every color is used as the color of a neighbour vertex?

(Two vertices are neighbours if they are the endpoints of an edge).

I transformed it into a coding problem.  I noticed that the vertices are vectors in $\mathbb{F}_2^{8}$.

Comment: a vertex is connected to $8$ other vertices

Comment: So, you think that the answer is 9?

Comment: at least we know it is at most 8

Comment: ok, but the proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://topologicalmusings.wordpress.com/2009/01/04/solution-to-pow-12-a-graph-coloring-problem/) is an article about this exercise.

Comment: The link above discusses two solutions of the problem, which was posed as [Problem of the Week (POW-12)](https://topologicalmusings.wordpress.com/2008/12/26/pow-12-a-graph-coloring-problem/) in the Topological Musings blog at the end of 2008.

Comment: While the link you posted provides solutions of this problem, it is good practice to quote (in addition) the most relevant part of the material found there, or to paraphrase the solution in your own words.  This will help Readers to decide whether to follow the link, and help to reconstruct the link should it become obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

Take a 7-dimensional face --- say $x_8 = 0$, which has $2^7$ vertices, of the form 
$b_1 b_2 \ldots b_7 0$.

Each is joined to the vertex
$$
b_1 b_2 \ldots b_7 1
$$
by an edge. So you can color each such pair a different color, and they'll satisfy your criterion. So the answer is "at least $2^7$ colors." I'll let you work out why it's at most $2^7$, and is therefore exactly $2^7$.

Comment: I have doubt about the answer because I need to find the maximum number of colors such that :I fixed a vertex and then I want another vertex who is him neighbour and colored with one of the colors.In the same time I want to  find a vertex for each color

Comment: @HenningMakholm

Comment: Agreed...Henning beat me to it. But his answer and mine are the same, so I think that if you accept his answer, you should have no doubts about mine.

Comment: And now I see that the perils of language were what confused both Henning and me. You wrote " .. such that foe every vertex of the cube, every color what was used it is a color of a neighbour vertex ?" Henning and I both interpreted this as "if a vertex $v$ has color $b$, then some neighbor of v also has color $b$." Our solutions correctly solve that problem. What was intended was "If $B$ is the set of all colors in the coloring, then for any vertex $v$, and every color $b \in B$, some neighbor of $v$ has color b$." The article matt points to solves **that** problem very nicely.

Comment: Hi @JohnHughes  $$$$
I want to show that $\sum_{i=0}^{\rho} \binom{n}{i} (q-1)^i \leq (n q)^p$. 

I thought to use the fact that $\sum_{i=0}^{\rho} \binom{n}{i} (q-1)^i \leq \sum_{i=0}^{\rho} \binom{\rho}{i} (nq-1)^i$. 

I tried to prove this but for $n=1$ it doesn't hold. Does it hold for greater $n$ ? 

Or do we have to use something else?

Comment: Surely if you want an answer, the right thing to do is post a question rather than a comment on an unrelated question.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to color the vertices such that every vertex is neighbor to at least one vertex of the same color, and you want to maximize the number of colors used?

Let the first 7 coordinates of each point determine its color, with $2^7=128$ different colors used. The last coordinate is not used, so for any vertex, flipping that coordinate between 0 and 1 will produce a neighbor of the same color.

On the other hand, your restriction clearly implies that every used color is used by at least two vertices, so with only 256 vertices in total, it is impossible to have *more than* 128 colors.